# How to replace IN () with Conditional inner join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

```
Table1 (ID, Col1, col2, col3, col4)

Table2 (ID, Col5, col6)

-----------------SP-------------------

set @Ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9' // Input paremeter  (can be NULL)

Create Table #Tabel2
(
     Id int
)
Insert into #table2 select * from dbo.Split(@Ids, ',')
```

NOW `#table2` has: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

**Scenario**

```
Select t1.Col1,t1.col2,t1.col3 
FROM Table1 as t1 
  INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Col1=t2.Col2
    AND (@Ids is null OR t1.ID in (Select Id from #Table2))
```

**Question**

How to replace `IN` with conditional inner join?

Comment: Please tag with which version of SQL you're using - e.g. Mysql, Sql Server, Oracle etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because you used alias `t` which was never defined in your query, it is not clear to me which table `ID` should be joined on. I took a guess and used `t1`.

```
Select t1.Col1,t1.col2,t1.col3 
FROM Table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.Col1=t2.Col2 
left outer join #Table2 ids on @Ids is null or t1.ID = ids.ID --maybe this should be t2.ID = ids.ID?
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding (it is friday afternoon after all) you want all rows from Table1/Table2, matched to #Table2 where possible, but everything if #Table2 is empty - this is simply an outer join.

```
SELECT t.Col1,
       t.col2,
       t.col3
FROM   Table1 AS t1
       INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
         ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN #Table2 t3
         ON t2.ID = t3.ID
```

Comment: It gives same records in both case when @Ids is null and not null.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2008, you can use CASE statements in your join clause, for example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON CASE WHEN table1.column1 = 'this' THEN null ELSE 'that' END = table2.column1
```